# `std::move` objects into constructor when returning composite type?

Tags: c++, move

I have a class which has several (potentially large) `std::vector<T>` members. As far as I know, this is not considered bad style. Simplified example:

```cpp
// C++17
#include<vector>

struct ThreeVectors {
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;
    std::vector<int> v3;
};
```

Then I also have a function, which computes some `std::vector<int>` from arguments and returns them wrapped into a `ThreeVectors` object:

```cpp
ThreeVectors no_move(const std::vector<int> &vv1, // copy manually in the function
                     std::vector<int> vv2,  // copy when passing argument
                     const std::vector<int> &vv3 // copy when wrapping into ThreeVectors
) {
    auto modvv = vv1;  // make a copy
    // perform lots of manipulations, including changing size (e.g. filtering).
    modvv.at(0)++;

    vv2.at(0)++;  // perform lots of manipulations

    // do nothing with vv3.

    return ThreeVectors{modvv, vv2, vv3};
}
```

Example user code:

```cpp
void user() {
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;
    std::vector<int> v3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10'000'000; ++i) {
        v1.push_back(i % 10'000);
        v2.push_back(i % 11'000 + 30);
        v3.push_back(i % 12'000 + 60);
    }

    auto wrapped = no_move(v1, v2, v3);
    // no longer need v2. Could std::move it if that helps?
    // still need v1 and v3. Cannot avoid one copy but avoid more?
    // ...
}
```

**Question: Should I be using move operations anywhere to make this more efficient?**

In particular, the following questions may be interesting:

1. The `user` may be calling `no_move` with a vector that the `user` no longer needs. Does it make sense to move it into the function (which only makes sense for arguments where the function does not accept by `const&`)?
2. Should the function never accept a `const&` if it has to make a copy anyway?
3. Should `no_move` be moving things into the constructor of `ThreeVectors`?
4. Does the fact that `no_move` does not modify its last argument but only wraps it play any role in how that argument should be treated?

I tried profiling different combinations of places where I could put `std::move` with quick-bench.com but I keep getting runtime errors (which probably means I'm using `std::move` incorrectly). Rather than spam my question with all the different combinations, all of which compile but many of which crash at runtime, I'm asking for the best-practice solution.

Comment: Bit of a judgement call.  My project's guidance is to do `ThreeVectors no_move(std::vector<int> vv1, std::vector<int> vv2, std::vector<int> vv3)` because all three are *sink* parameters.  And for the return, `return {std::move(vv1), std::move(vv2), std::move(vv3)};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, the rule is that taking `const&` is counterproductive when you're going to copy anyway. The only thing that does is make it impossible to avoid the copy. Take *by value*, and move from the value inside `no_move`, and then the user code can decide whether the argument can be moved or if it must be copied. No, the fact that `vv3` is forwarded but `vv1` manipulated does not mean they're treated differently. The only thing that matters is that the function is "taking ownership" of both.

Also, note that `ThreeVectors` doesn't have a constructor. It is initialized by aggregate initialization, which initializes each field as if by `field(initializer);` (copy-initialization). So you better put `std::move`s in there.

```
ThreeVectors no_move(std::vector<int> vv1, // copy OR move from user
                     std::vector<int> vv2, // copy OR move from user
                     std::vector<int> vv3  // copy OR move from user
) {
    vv1.at(0)++;
    vv2.at(0)++;
    return {std::move(vv1), std::move(vv2), std::move(vv3)};
}
```

Notice that getting it right is *simpler* than getting it wrong.

```
void user() {
    std::vector<int> v1, v2, v3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10'000'000; ++i) {
        v1.push_back(i % 10'000);
        v2.push_back(i % 11'000 + 30);
        v3.push_back(i % 12'000 + 60);
    }
    auto wrapped = no_move(v1, std::move(v2), v3);
    // say what you mean:
    //  1. v1 and v3 must remain under user's ownership and no_move must
    //     receive copies, since it also wants ownership
    //  2. user no longer needs v2 and it can just be given to no_move
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should.

To your questions:

1. Yes, `move` when you don't need it anymore, so it doesn't get copied
2. Yes, unless it has fast paths that might be able to avoid the copy. Receiving by value creates the possibility of receiving an r-value that can be cheaply move-constructed; receiving `const` reference precludes that.
3. Yes.
4. Receiving by `const` reference is arguable there. If you receive by value, and `std::move` to `ThreeVectors`, you guarantee one move construction, plus either one move or one copy construction. If you receive by `const` reference, you always do a copy construction, but no move construction at all. For `std::vector`, I'd probably receive by value and `std::move` into the `ThreeVector`s. Alternatively, you could receive it by r-value reference (`&&`), but that limits the use a bit more.

So my suggestion are:

1. The function itself should receive `vv1` by value; there is no reason to receive by `const` reference when it'll be copied internally without being used via reference anyway
2. `return ThreeVectors{modvv, vv2, vv3};` should be `return ThreeVectors{std::move(modvv), std::move(vv2), vv3};`; (`vv1` instead of `modvv` if you receive it by value as suggested) copy elision can handle not copying the `ThreeVectors` instance itself (it's returned and RVO applies), but figuring out how to elide the copy into the new `ThreeVectors` is hard, and very unlikely to happen.
3. When calling the function, do it with `auto wrapped = no_move(v1, std::move(v2), v3);`; if you followed the advice in #1, this will copy construct from `v1` (inefficient but leaves it unmodified as desired), move construct from `v2` (efficient) and receive the unmodified `v3` by reference. Without `std::move`, `v2` would be copied, wasting memory and time.
4. Optionally, it may make sense to receive `v3` by value as well, since the incremental cost of adding a move when a copy is needed is small relative to the benefit of only using two moves when a copy can be avoided.

If I were writing the API, I'd do it as:

```
ThreeVectors no_move(std::vector<int> vv1,
                     std::vector<int> vv2,
                     std::vector<int> vv3
) {
    // perform lots of manipulations, including changing size (e.g. filtering).
    vv1.at(0)++;

    vv2.at(0)++;  // perform lots of manipulations

    // do nothing with vv3.

    return {std::move(vv1), std::move(vv2), std::move(vv3)};
}
```

with your specific use being:

```
auto wrapped = no_move(v1, std::move(v2), v3);
```

involving two copy constructions and four move constructions (simply strategically adding `std::move` but otherwise leaving your original code unchanged would have two copy constructions and three move constructions), but with the possibility of other callers potentially calling it with:

```
auto wrapped = no_move(std::move(v1), std::move(v2), std::move(v3));
```

thereby avoiding *all* copy construction overhead (just six move constructions) when the caller's `vector`s need not be preserved.